# Get property value and check for existence and null

Tags: android, json, gson

I am writing a custom deserializer for a json object and I have a property in the json that may not exist and if it exists its value may be null.

```
JsonObject obj = ....;
String value = "";
// first check if exists
if (obj.has("someProperty")) {
    // get the proprty
    JsonElement element = obj.get("someProperty");
    // better check if its null
    if (!element.isJsonNull()) {
       // ah yes finally have the value
       value = element.getAsString();
    }
}
```

Yup works great, but extremely verbose.  Combing the GSON api to find a better way with no luck.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one would be a little bit better:

```
JsonElement element = obj.get("someProperty");
if (element != null && !element.isJsonNull()) {
    value = element.getAsString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use org.json.JSONObject; and do the following.

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        String value = "";
        // will set value to your element if it exists otherwise will return empty string
        value = obj1.optString("someProperty");
```